# The token was already consumed by another rule, Can't parse the token again

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent

I am constructing an LL(1) parser (Recursive Descent Parser) and I need to parse the sentence `a = 3`, I have two procedures to match that rule: `parse_assignment` and `parse_binary_operator`,

each function consumes the first token, and then it needs to see whether the operator (`=`) matches the rule, so I call firstly `parse_assignment` which consumes the token "a", and then consumes "=", and then consumes "3". In case the function failed (didn't match), I try to match the next rule.

but what if I want to parse the sentence `a - 1`?
I try to call `parse_assignment` but then it consumes `a` and fails, and then I try to call `parse_binary_operator` but the token "a" was already consumed so that function only has"`-1`" to parse now.

So I need to somehow return the token to the stream in case the function didn't match, but I don't think returning the token back to the stream is a good idea, I guess there are more stable techniques to do that.

Comment: FWIW, it is not uncommon for recursive descent parsers to push a (single) token back to the scanner in case of failure to match the current production. -- Another approach is to hoist the common prefix into a shared production.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will consider it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "(1)" in "LL(1)" indicates that the parser is allowed to consult (1) unconsumed token in order to decide which action to take. This token is usually called the "lookahead" token, because the parser can look ahead at it without actually consuming it. Whatever interface you implement between your parser and your lexer must somehow implement this feature; otherwise, you will run into precisely the problem you mention.

The precise nature of this interface will depend on which language you are using to write your parser, so it's hard to give a concrete answer. But basically, the lexical analyser will have two fundamental methods:

- `peek`, which returns the token type of the lookahead token. (A token usually has a number of additional features, all of which should be available in some way through `peek`, or other methods which are also views of the lookahead token. These include the semantic value of the token, if any, and some indication of where the token is in the source file.
- `consume`, which discards the lookahead token and replacing it with the next input token.

There are other possible interfaces, which are essentially equivalent. For example, it's common to implement a boolean convenience function like "match an X and consume the token on success", although that might not be so convenient if you also need to return the semantic value of the matched token.

The lookahead token is part of the state of the lexical analyser, which also includes information like the string currently being parsed and the current input position in that string. It was once common to store this state in global variables (which is what the lexical analysers built with the assistance of (f)lex do), but this makes it much harder to write a program with two different lexical analysers. Modern programming style discourages the use of global variables, which leaves the necessity to include the lexical analyser's state (or object) in the parser state (or object), or to explicitly pass a reference to the lexical analyser's state through the recursive parsing calls.

Comment: I managed to parse all of other stuff correctly by having a current_token and next_token, and an advance() function which assigns next_token to current_token and puts the next token in next_token. that's one lookahead indeed.

Comment: You can take a look, please tell me if I did something wrong https://github.com/jonatan1609/JoLang

Comment: @Jonathan1609 perhaps I misunderstood your question. You can't parse an LL(2) granmar with an LL(1) parser. You need to make sure the grammar is LL(1).

Comment: I think I didn't express myself good, for example given either "a=2" or "a-2", I try to match it with an assignment expression, this way: first I need to consume the "a", which is the first token, and then I have one lookahead and I can see the "=" or "-" without consuming it. (if I didn't want to consume the "a" and although see the "="/"-" without consuming it I would have to use LL(2)). and after I consumed "a" and saw that the operator is "=", i know that this is an assignment in case the line was "a=2", but what if the line was "a-2"? then I need to go back and try to parse it with ->

Comment: then I need to go back and try to parse it with the other production matcher, parse_binary_operator, instead of parse_assignment, but the issue here is that I can't parse this line since I consumed the first token in parse_assignment so currently I am left with "=2", and that's not good.

Comment: @Jonathan1609: but you know how to parse `a*2` and `a-1`. Why does assignment have to be different?

Comment: `Assignment: Literal "=" Literal;`
`BinaryOperator: Literal "-" Literal` is definitely LL(1)

Comment: because I don't consider assignment as a regular operator like -,* it's a statement. I don't want to allow it like (a=2). (inside of an expression).

Comment: @Jonathan1609: no, it isn't. In an LL(1) grammar, two different alternatives cannot start with the same token.

Comment: And you have two alternatives for statement starting with identifier

Comment: Oh, that's new to me. So how was old cpython's parser an LL(1) (until py3.10 before they used PEG). in python you can do a=3 and a+3 and yet it was LL(1)

Comment: It was pretty hacky but I don't recall the details. They're in the git history, though.

Comment: Hmm ok. so as a parsing expert, what do you suggest? 1: redesigning the grammar to only allow `var a = 3` so I can know assignment by the keyword `var`. 2: converting my parser to LL(2) by simply adding more variable (like next_next_token). 3: push the token back to the stream and match with the other rule?

Comment: Nothing stops you from parsing `=` like any operator. That gets you a superset of the language, so you have to do a check in the action. Or you can use an LR(1) parser, which doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Or left-factor your grammar. But that's really painful.

Comment: I don't want to parse = as an operator because then expressions like a+1=3 would be allowed, and I don't like it. the maximum I can allow is like the walrus operator that python has. XD. but LR would require me to rewrite the parser from scratch wouldn't it?

Comment: As I said, just because you parse something doesn't mean you have to accept it. You are free to do additional checks in the actions. Python does that all over the place. If you only want to allow `=` as the top-level operator, that's an easy check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239007/discussion-between-jonathan1609-and-rici).

Comment: Note that Python accepts destructuring assignment, like `(a, [b, d]) = ...` so the left-hand syntax is very hard to distinguish from an expression. But the parser manages. I'm pretty sure that was accomplished with an extragrammatical check, but I could be wrong.